# SQl Query using Self Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this

```
YR    Game
1960  football
1961  football
1962  football
1962  tennis
1963  football
1963  golf
1965  football
1965  tennis 
1965  golf
1967  tennis
1967  volleyball
```

How do I write a query using join to find the year which has to have football as the game but not tennis..

Answer (score 3):

You can use a WHERE filter to get the result:

```
select yr, game
from yt
where game = 'Football'
  and yr not in (select yr
                 from yt
                 where game = 'tennis');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fa9/1)

Comment: This worked! Thank you..Is there a way to get this working using join?

Comment: You can use a left join like landons answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins to filter this (downside is you need indexes on both columns):

```
SELECT YR FROM table AS a
LEFT JOIN table AS b ON b.YR = a.YR AND b.Game = 'tennis'
WHERE a.Game = 'football' AND b.Game IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Query ?

```
select game_year from table_game a left outer join table_game b on a.game_year= 
b.game_year and b.game = 'tennis' where a.game = 'football' and coalesce(b.game, '') = ''
```